# Behaviour of spin under rotations

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, rotation, spinors

Consider a spin-half particle measured, in some direction, to be up. If we put the particle again in the measurement device rotated by an angle of 180 degrees (around an axis orthogonal to the axis of the measurement), the measure should be down. Am I right?

Let $m \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}$ and consider a particle of spin $m$. Assume that it is measured to have spin up in some direction by a device. By what angle should one turn the measurement device to be sure that if we put the particle back, the spin should be measured as down?

In fact, I would like to find out, by myself, what the symmetries of a $m$-spin particle should be, in terms of matrices; this is why I would like to know, from a physical point of view, what to expect, in order to be able to carry out the mathematical computations.

Comment: 180 degrees, of course.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: And I deleted the "homework-exercises" tag because it is not a homework.

Comment: Any reference would be appreciated here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524676/mathematical-reference-about-spin

Answer (score 0):

In nuclear magnetic resonance physics we use *Bloch vectors* to represent the spin state. The spin state $\vec e_z = |up_z\rangle$ is represented by the Bloch vector $(0,0,1)$. Now, if we rotate this state by $180^{\circ}$ w.r.t. the $z$ axis, the state does not change. Hence, a rotation by $180^{\circ}$ does not always change the state.

However, if we rotate the state by $180^{\circ}$  about an axis, which lies in the $xy$ plane, we obtain the $(0,0,-1)=-\vec e_z = |down_z\rangle$. The rotation is usually called a $\pi$-rotation around the $(x,y,0)$-axis. Two particular simple realisations of this rotation is a

1. $\pi$-pulse around the $x$ axis and
2. $\pi$-pulse around the $y$ axis.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I edited my question. My question only concerns rotations around axes that are orthogonal to the axis of measurement.